# Should This Be In Its Own Stylesheet, and How? (PHP In Stylesheet?)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header

Building a WordPress options panel.  One of the things it does is allow users to pick custom colors.  I use a default stylesheet, then call styles for custom inputs.  However, I simply insert this in the header instead of having these custom values reside in their own stylesheet (since I need to call the user's choice via PHP).

As an example, I have code in my header like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
p a { <?php echo get_option('to_custom_css'); ?> }
</style>
```

And in my functions:

```
array( "name" => "Custom CSS",  
    "desc" => "Want to add any custom CSS code? Put in here, and the rest is taken care of. This overrides any other stylesheets. eg: a.button{color:green}",  
    "id" => $shortname."_custom_css",  
    "type" => "text",  
    "std" => ""),
```

How would I have this reside in its own stylesheet while still using `<?php echo get_option('to_custom_css'); ?>` to call the users input?

Comment: ...this is the saddest news I've heard all day.

Comment: See answer by daiscog for what appears to be a workaround.

Comment: @LucasWynne you can if you set the stylesheet's extension to .php.  Or if you are using Apache, you can set any specific file to be handled by PHP, or even use mod_rewrite to pass all requests for some_file.css to some_other_file.php.  You just need to remember to set the Content-type header in your PHP file to "text/css".

Comment: Do you need to have the style within the theme or within the dashboard/admin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a stylesheet in PHP, but need to set the Content-type header to text/css.  In your HTML:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="user-styles.php" />
  <!-- ... -->
```

The in user-styles.php:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/css');

?>
/*  now put your css here : */

p a { 
    <?php echo get_option('to_custom_css'); ?> 
}

/* and so on... */
```

Answer (score 3):

First, add this to your `.htaccess` file so that it will interpret php found in css files:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
```

Then, link to the external stylesheet. Make the link dynamically include the information needed to determine the user's css values (probably an id number), like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.yourserver.com/customstyle.css?id=<?php echo $userid; ?>" type="text/css" />
```

Finally, put php code in the stylesheet that prints out the css dynamically, like this:

```
<?php echo get_option('to_custom_css'); ?>
```

Use `$_GET['parametername']` to retrieve the parameters allowing you to calculate the css data.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you should be writing out the CSS to a file that can be included from the hosting page. That way it can be cached by the browser.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="user1024/style.css" />
```

Comment: Any PHP file can be cached by the browser.  Just set the relevant HTTP headers.